# Return all results where the purchase made date is within 7 days of the registration date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, inner-join, where-clause

I have so far produced the below code to try and pull the relevant data together.

However with the '+ 7' function it is producing the below issue.

```
Registration date = '2018-01-01'
```

It is pulling back purchase dates of `2018-04-08`, i.e as long as the day of the day is 7 days greater then it is being deemed acceptable. When in reality what I ma looking for is any all purchases within 7 days of the registration date.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select *
from purchases b
inner join registrations r
on r.customer_id = b.customer_id
and day(b.purchase_date) between d(r.account_opening_date) and day(r.account_opening_date) + 7
and r.account_opening_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00.0'
```

Comment: So if +7 is too many, have you tried using +6 and 23:59:59 (ie, less than 7 days instead of less than or equal)

Comment: did you try without the day() function?
what you're doing is literally only check the "day" and not the entire date

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_ADD instead, DAY() will not work well when dates to compare are in different months.

```
AND b.purchase_date >= r.account_opening_date AND 
    b.purchase_date <= DATE_ADD(r.account_opening_date INTERVAL 7 Day)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, very useful

Answer (score 0):

you can use window function

```
 select *
 partition by (order by account_opening_date rows 6 preceding)
 from purchases p, registrations r
 where p.customer_id = r.customer_id
 and r.account_opening_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00.0'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot very useful

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) MySQL functions.

```
select *
from purchases b
inner join registrations r
on r.customer_id = b.customer_id
and date(b.purchase_date) between date(r.account_opening_date) and date_add(r.account_opening_date interval 7 day)
and r.account_opening_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00.0'
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `+`:

```
select *
from purchases b inner join
    registrations r
    on r.customer_id = b.customer_id and
       b.purchase_date >= r.account_opening_date and 
       b.purchase_date < r.account_opening_date + interval 7 day
where r.account_opening_date >= '2018-01-01';
```

If you want to do this without the time component, then use the `date()` function:

```
    on r.customer_id = b.customer_id and
       b.purchase_date >= r.account_opening_date and 
       b.purchase_date <= date(r.account_opening_date) + interval 7 day
where r.account_opening_date >= '2018-01-01'
```

Whether you use `<` or `<=` depends on the exactly interpretation of "within 7 days".  This version assumes that you really want 7-8 days.